# $\int^{\pi}_0 \log (1+\cos x)dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \log (1+cosx)dx $$

My approach :

$\displaystyle I = \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1+\cos x)dx $

Also $$\displaystyle I = \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1+\cos(\pi -x)dx ....(1)$$ [ Using $\displaystyle \int^a_0 f(x)dx = \int^a_0 f(a-x)dx]$
$$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1-\cos xdx) ......(2) $$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$2I = \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1+\cos(\pi -x) + \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1-\cos xdx) dx$$

$$\Rightarrow 2I = \int^{\pi}_0 \log (1-\cos^2 x)dx $$

$$\Rightarrow 2I = \int^{\pi}_0 2 \log \sin x dx$$

Please suggest how to proceed further will be of great help thanks.

Comment: The answer to integral of $2ln(sinx)dx$ on interval $(0,\pi/2)$ happens to be $-\pi*ln2$ if that helps...It's late over here. IF the answer helps (remember that from 0 to pi/2 and from pi/2 to pi the sine behaves "the same") and you need the work, then I can type that up later...

Comment: I posted a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085863/what-kind-of-contour-if-any-can-be-used-for-these-types-of-trigonometric-integ) some time ago, though I was interested in finding $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln(\color{red}{2}+\cos x)\,dx$$You might find the method in the edit helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Let $I$ be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi}\log (\sin x)\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log (\sin x)\,dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\log (\sin x)\,dx\tag 2
\end{align}$$

**Substitution $1$:**   Let $x\to 2x$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  Then,

$$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \sin (2x)\,dx\tag 3$$

**Substitution $2$:**   Let $x\to \pi-x$ in the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log (\sin x)\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\log (\cos x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \frac 12\sin(2x)\,dx\\\\
&=-(\pi/2)\log (2)+\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \sin(2x)\,dx\tag 4
\end{align}$$

Upon comparing $(3)$ and $(4)$ we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \sin(2x)\,dx=-(\pi/2)\log 2\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I=-\pi\log 2}$$

Comment: I've been working on a solution for a while, but it involved special functions... While I usually don't mind using them in proofs, your solution here is simply ingenious to solve it without them.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks!  There are many ways to "skin  an integral," I was told a wise man once said.  I always enjoy seeing alternative approaches to solving a problem.  So, don't give up on looking at the ones you pursued.  Even if they don't pan out, you might gain insights that can be used later.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)dx.................(*)$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$$

so we get $$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-\cos x)dx............(*)$$

Now Add these two equations, We get

$$\displaystyle \displaystyle 2I  = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1-\cos^2 x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\sin x)dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin x)dx$$

Now Using  $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2a}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx\;,$$ If $f(2a-x) = f(x)$

So we get  $$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln (\sin x)dx $$

$$\underline{\bf{Calculation \; of\; \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln (\sin x)dx\;}}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(2x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\Big(\log(2)+\log(\sin(x))+\log(\cos(x))\Big)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)+2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag{2}
$$

Thus,
$$
\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\log(2)
$$

Comment: But how does one obtain $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log \sin x\,dx$? The OP already arrived at that integral.  May I suggest you expand your answer?

Comment: Thanks Dr. MV, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Well done.  And you're quite welcome.  That is the cool thing about this site; we help each other work through problems and can constructively suggest alternative ways to address concerns of the OP.  ;-))

Comment: Oh ... +1 by the way!

Comment: You're welcome Juan!  - Mark

Comment: I wake up and there is the work....Juantheron worked out what I had in mind...+1